# How to enable the startup options in an Access database project using Shift Key?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I disabled the startup options of my access project(.accdb) using this code from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/826765/how-to-enforce-or-disable-the-startup-options-in-an-access-database-pr). And it worked after I type in the immediate window to disable to shift key.

But how can I re enable the shift key again since I cannot go through with the code anymore since it is now hidden and all I can see now is this.

[image]

Any idea how can I view the immediate window again to enable the shift key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Bypass key from VBA code in another database. This will be the only way if also disabled special keys like Alt-F11. Here is modified code from [Microsoft site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826765/how-to-enforce-or-disable-the-startup-options-in-an-access-database-pr). Create this function in another database and modify path to your protected database:

```
Function ap_EnableShift()
    'This function enables the SHIFT key at startup. This action causes
    'the Autoexec macro and the Startup properties to be bypassed
    'if the user holds down the SHIFT key when the user opens the database.

    On Error GoTo errEnableShift

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim prop As DAO.Property
    Const conPropNotFound = 3270

    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\path\tst.accdb")

    'This next line of code enables the SHIFT key on startup.
    db.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = True

    'function successful
    Exit Function

errEnableShift:
    'The first part of this error routine creates the "AllowByPassKey
    'property if it does not exist.
    If Err = conPropNotFound Then
        Set prop = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", _
            dbBoolean, True)
        db.Properties.Append prop
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Function 'ap_DisableShift' did not complete successfully."
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```